# What type of printer port is this?

Tags: connector, serial, port

I just got a currency discriminator (Carnation CR1500) that can be connected to a receipt printer. There is a modular jack on the back of the machine, but I don't know what kind of cable it needs. It won't accept RJ45 or RJ11 connectors. It's taller and thinner than any RJ port I've seen and there's nothing in the manual about it.

[image: Printer port]

Can anyone identify this?

Comment: An email to the company might solve this problem

Comment: @laptop2d: To my experience, companies in the POS industry treat their technical datasheets as trade secrets, not something which enables the end customer using their product.

Comment: @Janka Looks like you might be right. Figuring out which contact is which won't be a problem. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely an RJ10 (earphone cord) connector with ±5V RS232 on it. That's what common receipt printers accept.

You have to find out yourself which pin is TxD, RxD and GND. In idle state, TxD has -5V against GND.